# Ubuntu folder not showing in external hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, backup, external-hdd

I backed up 2 folders (containing .py files) from my Ubuntu 20 OS to the external hard drive.

While trying to see the files on the external hard drive from Windows 10, I can't find those. Please advise

Comment: What is the format of the drive? ExFAT, Ext3/4, NTFS? Windows does not play well with standard Linux file systems. ExFAT is a good option for interoperability, though other options exist.

Comment: The format of the external HDD drive is NTFS

Answer (score 0):

Windows supported file systems: `NTFS`, `FAT` and `exFAT`, [wikipedia:File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)

And usually Ubuntu uses the `ext` (now ext4) file system.

You can run commands in linux to check which type is used for external drives.

```
df -Th
```

It will display the following

```
...               Type  ... Mounted on
...  <filesystem type>  ... <your external hard drive>
```

One way to solve the problem is to format your external hard drive as `NTFS`/`exFAT` (this is also readable/writable in Linux), remember to backup your data before formatting.